# Performance: tf.read_file(filename) vs. tf.WholeFileReader()

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a difference in performance (in sense of pre-fetching) between `tf.read_file(filename)` vs. `tf.WholeFileReader()`?

For example, is there a difference in the performance between these two code samples:

```
def example_read_file():
    filename_list = tf.convert_to_tensor([["file1_1", "file1_2", "file1_3"], ["file2_1", "file2_2", "file2_3"]])
    filename_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer(filename_list)

    f0 = tf.read_file(filename_queue[0])
    f1 = tf.read_file(filename_queue[1])
    f2 = tf.read_file(filename_queue[2])

    loss = calculate_loss(f0, f1, f2)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        for i in range(0, 10):
            print(sess.run([loss]))

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)

def example_WholeFileReader():
    filename_list = tf.convert_to_tensor([["file1_1", "file1_2", "file1_3"], ["file2_1", "file2_2", "file2_3"]])
    fn0, fn1, fn2 = tf.split(1, 3, filename_list)

    # queues
    fq0 = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.reshape(fn0, [-1]), shuffle=False)
    fq1 = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.reshape(fn1, [-1]), shuffle=False)
    fq2 = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.reshape(fn2, [-1]), shuffle=False)

    # read files
    r0 = tf.WholeFileReader()
    k0, v0 = r0.read(fq0)
    r1 = tf.WholeFileReader()
    k1, v1 = r1.read(fq1)
    r2 = tf.WholeFileReader()
    k2, v2 = r2.read(fq2)

    loss = calculate_loss(v0, v1, v2)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        for i in range(0, 10):
            print(sess.run([loss]))

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see prefetching of data for either of them. To reading files asynchronously, you need to setup prefetching queue. Batch functions already do this for you, ie `f0_, f1_, f2_=tf.train.batch([f0, f1, f2])` will load contents of files into queue asynchronously when queue runners are started, new tensors `f0_, f1_, f2_` pull contents from that queue

Comment: Hi Yaroslav, thanks a lot for your fast response and the insights! So, if I use example `example_read_file` with the `tf.batch`-function, the data will be fetched asynchronously. But probably only with one thread which reads all files?

Comment: There's `num_threads` parameter for batch, so reading will be done with that many threads.. The difference between `read_file` and `WholeFileReader` is that former uses `ReadFile` op and latter uses `WholeFileReaderV2` op defined in `io_ops.cc`. Not sure if there's any performance difference between them, but `WholeFileReaderV2` is newer

Comment: perfect! Thanks a lot!